# How can i open a powerpoint presentation using Powerpoint.createPresentation with a custom title

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, office-addins, powerpoint-addins, powerpoint-web-addins

I'm using `PowerPoint.createPresentation` to open a new presentation from my officejs addin.

For the `PowerPoint.createPresentation` i pass the base64 value of another presentation, where i can use `Aspose` to change the data.

The newly opened presentations are named `Presentation1,2,..,n`.

I can change somehow the default name of the new presentation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`OfficeJS` doesn't provide any method for saving the file/presentation. See [Office JS Save and Close methods for Word, Excel and PowerPoint](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/office-js-save-and-close-methods-for-word-excel-and-powerpoint/idi-p/2800214) for more information.

Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when the dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: `Type: product feature request` at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .

Comment: I'm interested on opening the new presentation with a different name than "Presentation1", not saving the file

Comment: There is no way unfortunately. Use the following link for posting suggestions - https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions